How to make Symfony working with tests folders
I would like to add a "tests" folder in Symfony.
Here is my composer.json :
    "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "AppBundle\\": "src/AppBundle"
    },
    "classmap": [
        "app/AppKernel.php",
        "app/AppCache.php"
    ]
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Tests\\": "tests/"
    },
    "files": [
        "vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/VarDumper/Resources/functions/dump.php"
    ]
},

So i add a controller into tests/Controller/TestController.php with a route /Test/Timeout
When i call the route with Postman : No route found for "GET /Test/Timeout"
When i run php bin/console debug:router, the route does not appear.
Did i miss something ?
If i put the TestController into src/AppBundle/Controller the route is find.

Why are you trying to have a functionnal controller in your tests folder ?

is it better to have it in the AppBundle folders ?

Is your controller used by your application in a way that you cannot delete it ? If yes it does not belong in tests. As the name says, the tests folder is meant for things like unit (phpunit) tests, application tests... You should not have actual controller with working route in your tests folder. The source of your application belong in your src folder.

The "tests" folder is designated for unit (and other types of) tests, typically executed by the PHPUnit framework, and it is not considered a part of the application itself. You shouldn't put controllers there.
However, if you wish to place your controller in the "tests" folder, you need to register the routes in the "config/routes.yaml". As you can put your controllers anywhere you want, you must also inform the router accordingly.
# //config/routes.yaml
controllers:
    resource:
        path: ../src/Controller/
        namespace: App\Controller
    type: attribute
test_controllers:
    resource:
        path: ../tests/Controller/
        namespace: App\Test\Controller
    type: attribute


This is correct to register routes, but once again: please do not use /tests folder as a source directory. As symfony tries to follow some logic in its skeleton that is more or less shared across different symfony projects.
